# Dynamic Checkbox value being posted twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a table of check boxes that are in a form that I am posting to the server.
 they all have a name value of `item.Commissionable`

When the request hits the controller I retrieve the values by

```
string[] itemCommissionableList = Request.Form.GetValues("item.Commissionable");
```

If a checkbox is checked there is two entries into the form and only one if it is not checked.

the check boxes are being added dynamically. The user either checks or un-checks the checkbox before it is added when they click the add button.

The code that is run when the user clicks the add button is

```
if (checkbox.isChecked)
        var supplierCommissionable = '<td><input checked  type="checkbox" /><input type="hidden" name="item.Commissionable" value="false"></td>';
    else
        var supplierCommissionable = '<td><input  type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="item.Commissionable" value="false"></td>';

container.append(supplierCommissionable)
```